# prove that $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have a doubt concerning this problem:

> Let $K \supset \mathbb Q$ be a field such that $[K:\mathbb Q]=m$ and let $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q$. If $\gcd\{m,n\}=1$, prove that $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$.

My attempt: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ be a root of $p(x)$. Now consider the fields $\mathbb {Q}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb {K}(\alpha)$ and supose that $[K(\alpha):K]=r$ and $[K(\alpha):\mathbb {Q}(\alpha)]=s$. It is true that $ns=mr$ and $\gcd\{m,n\}=1 \Rightarrow n|r$. How to proceed from now on in order to prove that $p(x)$ is also irreducible over $K$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any field $F$, any polynomial $q\in F[x]$, and any root $\beta$ of $q$, we have
$$[F(\beta):F]\leq\deg(q)$$
with equality if and only if $q$ is irreducible. Another way of saying this is that for any $\beta$ that is algebraic over $F$, we have
$$[F(\beta):F]=\text{the degree of $m_{\beta,F}\in F[x]$ (the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$)}$$
Because you've shown that $n$ divides $[K(\alpha):K]$ and it can be at most $n$, we must have
$$\deg(m_{\alpha,K})=[K(\alpha):K]=n=\deg(p)$$
But $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]\subset K[x]$ is a polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root, so the minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha,K}$ must divide it, that is,
$$m_{\alpha,K}\mid p$$
Because their degrees are equal, we must have $p=c\cdot m_{\alpha,K}$ for some constant $c$. In particular, $p$ is irreducible because $m_{\alpha,K}$ is by definition.

Comment: Hello, Curious! Why $r$ can be at most $r$? $

Comment: It's because of the fact I mentioned in the first sentence of my answer. Is your concern that you don't understand why that fact is true?

Comment: $m_{\alpha,k}$ and $m_{\alpha,\mathbb {Q}}$ are polynomials over different fields, so in principle there is no relation between them.

Comment: In fact, because $K\supseteq\mathbb{Q}$, we have $K[x]\supseteq\mathbb{Q}[x]$, i.e. any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a polynomial over $K$. In particular $m_{\alpha,\mathbb{Q}}$ is an element of $K[x]$ that has $\alpha$ as a root. It is a basic theorem that $m_{\alpha,K}$ divides all elements of $K[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root, so that $m_{\alpha,K}$ divides $m_{\alpha,\mathbb{Q}}$, and therefore
$$[K(\alpha):K]=\deg(m_{\alpha,K})\leq \deg(m_{\alpha,\mathbb{Q}})=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}]$$